# Convert PIL Image to Bytes, getting Error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-3.7, bytesio

The solutions I have found said to:

```
from PIL import Image
import io

img = "1.jpg"
image = Image.open(img)

# ... other processing...

buf = io.BytesIO()
image.save(buf, format="JPEG")
buf.get_value()
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'get_value'
```

If I try instead:

```
buf.seek(0)
```

It just outputs 0.

Those are the only two suggestions I have found and they are not working for me. Is it an issue with my versions?
I have Python 3.7.3 and PIL 6.1.0

Comment: I'm doing some operations using PIL before saving it, but I left it out in this code to simplify the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> buf.seek(0) # Return to beginning of buffer
>>> data = buf.read() # Read all bytes until EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all, `BytesIO` object has no attribute named `get_value`. The attribute is `getvalue()` and not `get_value()`. Refer the docs for more information https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO